# Convert the duplicated rows into multiple columns with headers

Tags: python, pandas

The input dataframe:

```
case    constant    number  code        
761e7   C20         3570    A   
761e7   C20         2780    A   
761e7   C20         7150    A   
761e7   C20         2950    A   
761e7   C20         3570    B   
761e7   C20         2780    B   
761e7   C20         7150    B   
761e7   C20         2950    B
761e7   C21         3000    A   
761e8   C20         3570    A   
761e8   C20         2780    A   
761e8   C20         7150    A   
761e8   C20         2950    A   
761e8   C14         3570    B   
761e8   C14         2780    B   
761e8   C14         7150    B
```

Trying to convert duplicated Numbers column into multiple columns based on other columns.

Pandas pivot conversion gives me an ValueError as shown

```
df = final_df.pivot(index='case', columns='number')

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

**Expected Output:**

```
case    constant    code    number1 number2 number3 number4 number5
761e7   C20         A       3570    2780    7150    2950    0
761e7   C21         A       0       0       0       0       3000
761e7   C20         B       3570    2780    7150    2950    0
761e8   C20         A       3570    2780    7150    2950    0
761e8   C14         B       3570    2780    7150    0       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
g = df.groupby(['case','constant','code'])

df_out = df.set_index(['case','constant','code',g.cumcount()+1]).unstack(fill_value=0)
df_out.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    case constant code  number1  number2  number3  number4
0  761e7      C20    A     3570     2780     7150     2950
1  761e7      C20    B     3570     2780     7150     2950
2  761e7      C21    A     3000        0        0        0
3  761e8      C14    B     3570     2780     7150        0
4  761e8      C20    A     3570     2780     7150     2950
```

Comment: It seems that your `3000` number is off.

Answer (score 1):

A more normal approach is to have your column names be the number values, and the rows contain counts -- e.g.:

```py
df.pivot_table(index=['case','constant','code'], 
               columns='number', aggfunc=len).reset_index()
```

yielding

```
number          case constant code  2780  2950  3000  3570  7150
0       7.610000e+09      C20    A     1     1     0     1     1
1       7.610000e+09      C20    B     1     1     0     1     1
2       7.610000e+09      C21    A     0     0     1     0     0
3       7.610000e+10      C14    B     1     0     0     1     1
4       7.610000e+10      C20    A     1     1     0     1     1
```